# Rendering multiple textures to a sphere based on game-generated values

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I'm making a game with my friend that involves randomly generating planets based on certain properties.  Originally this game was all 2D, but now we've decided to enhance the purpose of planets in the game and make it 2.5D, with planets being rendered as 3D spheres in an otherwise 2D world.  Now, up to this point we had a pretty good thing going with the way planets looked.  We used layered textures, one for each property (water, land, atmosphere) depending on how our algorithms created the planet.  This looked pretty, but the planet surfaces were largely lame and didn't vary as they were all made from the same few textures.

Now that we are going 3D, I want to create a nice planetary map which will determine the topography of the planet based on its properties to make each planet have different bodies of water, land masses, etc.  I also want to draw different textures on the surface of the planet based on that map, with them blending together at the edges.

I've considered two possibilities: rendering the textures based on the map to a RenderTarget and then wrapping that RenderTarget around my sphere model, or converting the map to vertex data and writing a shader to draw the textures with the proper weight.

The problem is, I'm a novice at both RenderTargets and HLSL (as a matter of fact, I don't even know if the RenderTarget method is possible), so I feel the need for some guidance here.  What would be recommended for rendering multiple textures to a sphere model based on a generated terrain map?  Also, are there any suggestions for what format to create the terrain map in (it would be some sort of data structure which would represent the type of terrain at any coordinate on the planet's surface)?

I have looked at other multi-texture tutorials, but they all seem based on a pre-determined texture or set of values.  I need to be able to randomly generate the terrain in-game.